# Convolution of multivariate Gaussian

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, convolution

Let $f: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a multivariate Gaussian and $g: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$ a multivariate dirac-function, namely with $i,j,m,n\in\mathbb N,m<n$ and $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ and $a,b\in\mathbb R$:

\begin{align}
& f(x)=
\frac {1}{\sqrt {(2\pi )^k|{\boldsymbol {\Sigma }}|}} \cdot \exp \left(-{\frac {1}{2}}({\mathbf {x} }-{\boldsymbol {\mu }})^{\mathrm {T} }{\boldsymbol {\Sigma }}^{-1}({\mathbf {x} }-{\boldsymbol {\mu }})\right) \\[10pt]
& g(x) = \begin{cases} \lim\limits_{a\rightarrow0,\ b\rightarrow\infty} \quad \dfrac{1}{a^m\cdot b^{n-m}} & |x_i|\le\frac a2,1\le i\le m,\quad |x_j|\le\frac b2,m<j\le n \\[6pt]
\quad 0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\end{align}

So bascially $g$ is a boxcar function where I have some of the borders shrink in some other expand, so that I get sort of a tube in 2D. If I have not done any mistakes the volume of $g$ should be $1.$ Let us further assume, the simplification that $\Sigma$ is a multiple of the identify matrix.

I would like to [convolve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) these two to $h(x) = (f ∗ g)(x)$. If we would have a regular dirac function with $\lim\limits_{a\rightarrow0,\ b\rightarrow0}$, then the result would be the $h(x)=f(x)$, however in my case this is not the case. Here, we get for the partially evaluated function

$$
h(x\mid\ x_i=c_i, m<i) = \text{constant}
$$

where all $c_i\in\mathbb R$. Now, my question: Is

$$
h(x\mid\ x_i=c_i, i\le m) \overset?\propto \exp \left(-{\frac {1}{2}}({\mathbf {x} }-{\boldsymbol {\mu }})^{\mathrm {T} }{\boldsymbol {\Sigma^\star }}^{-1}({\mathbf {x} }-{\boldsymbol {\mu }})\right) 
$$

a multivariate Gaussian (of dimension $m$)? How would $\Sigma^\star$ would be scaled compared to $\Sigma$?

Comment: You can write $g$ directly as $g(x) =\prod_{i=1}^m \delta(x_i)$. Hopefully now the convolution becomes more transparent.

Comment: The Fourier transform changes convolution to pointwise multiplication: $\widehat{f*g} = \widehat f \cdot\widehat {g\,}.$ And the Fourier transform of a Gaussian function is a Gaussian function. Multiply the two Fourier transforms and see what you get. $\qquad$

Comment: @user619894: It is not obvious to me, why I can write $g$ as you suggest, can you elaborate?

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Thank you for giving me those tips, but it does not get me all the way to the solution: The Fourier transform of the dirac delta function is 1, so in the spectrum, $1\cdot Gaussian$ is a Gaussian and getting it back to "normal", we have a Gaussian. But I knew that already (see my question), so I am not yet sure how this translates to me question. What is the Fourier transform of $g$?

Comment: I think that your definition of the "anti" delta in the $g$ shouldn't be normalized, since integrating over the $|x|<b/2$  with a $L_2$ test function, as it stands, will always give zero.

Comment: @user619894: I am not sure what you mean: I thought that $1 / (a^m \cdot a^{n-m})$ is already doing the normalization. Can you write the formula in an answer, or edit my post that I can see what you mean?

Comment: Consider the one dimensional case:  $m=0,n=1$ case $g={1\over b}{\bf 1}(|x|<b/2)$ ( $\bf 1$ is the indicator function), integrating over a test function $p(x)$ would yield ${1\over b} \int_{-b/2}^{b/2} p(x)dx$ . If  $\int_{-b/2}^{b/2} p(x)dx$ is bounded for large $b$, this will vanish in the large $b$ limit. Specifically for a Gaussian, as your example, this integral will vanish.

Comment: @user619894: Are you using $p$ as an alternative to $f$ as in $(f*g)(x)\triangleq\ \int _{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x-\xi)g(\xi)\,d\xi = \frac1b\int _{-b/2}^{b/2}f(x-\xi)\,d\xi$? Do you mean because $\lim_{b\rightarrow\infty}\int _{-b/2}^{b/2}f(\xi)\,d\xi=1$ for a Gaussian that the factor $1/b$ makes it $0$? If so - what do you suggest to correct this?

Comment: Precisely. I suggest not to divide by $b$

Comment: @user619894: But I would still divide by $a^m$? Either way: Does that not make $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x)dx = \infty$ or is that no issue?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:
I simplified the notation a bit to make the answer clearer.

I assume your limiting function $g$ should actually be $\prod_{i=1}^m \delta(x_i)$ ( the normalization by $1\over b$ will cause the entire convolution to vanish, so I treat it as a confusion). In that case, the convolution
$$ \int _{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x-\xi)g(\xi)\,d\xi $$
becomes
$$
 {1\over{\sqrt {(2\pi )^k|{\boldsymbol {\Sigma }}|}}} \int _{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp \left(-{\frac {1}{2}}({\mathbf {\xi} }-{\boldsymbol {\mu }})^{\mathrm {T} }{\boldsymbol {\Sigma }}^{-1}({\mathbf {\xi} }-{\boldsymbol {\mu }})\right) \prod_{i=1}^m \delta(x_i-\xi_i)\prod_{j=1}^{m} d\xi_j\prod_{k=m+1}^{n} d\xi_k
$$

At this point some simplification can be made by noticing that the $\xi$ are integration variables, and we can "swallow" the $\mu$ into them, integrating over $\xi-\mu$ instead. This leaves us with
$$
 {1\over{\sqrt {(2\pi )^k|{\boldsymbol {\Sigma }}|}}} \int _{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp \left(-{\frac {1}{2}}({\mathbf {\xi} })^{\mathrm {T} }{\boldsymbol {\Sigma }}^{-1}({\mathbf {\xi} })\right) \prod_{i=1}^m \delta(x_i-\xi_i-\mu_i)\prod_{j=1}^{m} d\xi_j\prod_{k=m+1}^{n} d\xi_k
$$

if we split the inverse covariance $\Sigma^{-1} $ into 4 parts: $\Sigma^{-1}_{<<};\Sigma^{-1}_{>>};\Sigma^{-1}_{><};\Sigma^{-1}_{<>}$ where the subscripts determine whether the indices are $i\le m;i>m$ respectively, we see that the expression in the exponent can be split into
$$({\mathbf {\xi} })^{\mathrm {T} }{\boldsymbol {\Sigma }}^{-1}({\mathbf {\xi} })
 = 
({\mathbf {\xi}_{<} })^{\mathrm {T} }
{\boldsymbol {\Sigma }}^{-1}_{<<}
({\mathbf {\xi}_{<} })+
({\mathbf {\xi}_{>} })^{\mathrm {T} }
{\boldsymbol {\Sigma }}^{-1}_{>>}
({\mathbf {\xi}_{>} })+
2({\mathbf {\xi_{<}} })^{\mathrm {T} }
{\boldsymbol {\Sigma }}^{-1}_{<>}
({\mathbf {\xi}_{>} })$$

The $\delta$'s enforce $\xi=x-\mu$ on the $_<$ indices, turning the expression in the exponent to
$$
({\mathbf {x}_{<} }-{\boldsymbol {\mu }_{<}})^{\mathrm {T} }
{\boldsymbol {\Sigma }}^{-1}_{<<}
({\mathbf {x}_{<} }-{\boldsymbol {\mu }}_{<})+
({\mathbf {\xi}_{>} })^{\mathrm {T} }
{\boldsymbol {\Sigma }}^{-1}_{>>}
({\mathbf {\xi}_{>} })+
2({\mathbf {x_{<}} }-{\boldsymbol {\mu }_{<}})^{\mathrm {T} }
{\boldsymbol {\Sigma }}^{-1}_{<>}
({\mathbf {\xi}_{>} })
$$
and we are left with an integral over the $\xi_>$ terms:
$$
 {1\over{\sqrt {(2\pi )^k|{\boldsymbol {\Sigma }}|}}}
\left(\exp(-{1\over2}({\mathbf {x}_{<} }-{\boldsymbol {\mu }_{<}})^{\mathrm {T} }
{\boldsymbol {\Sigma }}^{-1}_{<<}
({\mathbf {x}_{<} }-{\boldsymbol {\mu }}_{<}) \right)\int \prod d{\xi}_>
\exp\left(-{1\over2} \left(({\mathbf {\xi}_{>} })^{\mathrm {T} }
{\boldsymbol {\Sigma }}^{-1}_{>>}
({\mathbf {\xi}_{>} })+
2({\mathbf {x_{<}} }-{\boldsymbol {\mu }_{<}})^{\mathrm {T} }
{\boldsymbol {\Sigma }}^{-1}_{<>}
({\mathbf {\xi}_{>} }) \right)\right)
$$

which can be calculated by completing the square.

Comment: Ok, there is quite a bit for me to unpack: 1) It is not obvious to me, why $\prod_{i=1}^m \delta(x_i)$ satisfies my needs: Let $n=3,m=2$, then the value for $i=3$ is irrelevant, and $\delta(x_1\neq0)=0$, $\delta(x_1=0)=\infty$, $\delta(x_2\neq0)=0$ and $\delta(x_2=0)=\infty$ (I know, a lot of abuse of notation). But why would $\delta(x_1=0)\cdot\delta(x_2=0)$ have surface of 1 under the integral and why would $0\cdot\delta(x_2=0) =0$?

Comment: 2) In your first large formula: Why are there two $d\xi_{...}$, but only one integral symbol? Did you mean something like $\iint_{-\infty}^{\infty}$? The second one is $d\xi_{k}$, but I don't really see a $k$ within the integral? What am I missing?

Comment: 3) Am beginning to grasp what you wrote, but what do you mean with "completing the square"? In your last formula, is everything including and after the $\int$ a single real number? Is it 1 (which would make the integral under the entire last formula 1, as with a regular Gaussian)?

Comment: Regarding the delta functions, each one has area 1 for the single coordinate it describes. To understand what a delta function does you have to examine how it acts when you integrate it with a test function. So don't try to interpret $\delta(0)\delta(0)$ directly, rather think about the double integral $\int\int dx_1dx_2 f(x_1,x_2)\delta(x_1)\delta(x_2)$

Comment: Regarding the single integral, you are correct, I was trying to lighten the notation, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Regarding completing the square, you can google completing the square gaussian for some detailed explanations.

Comment: also, there was a typo , that is why the k was missing. I corrected

Comment: There are more typos, but since I got negative feedback, when I corrected them last time at a different question, I will just point them out: In the last formula after the $\frac12$ there should be a $($ and then later the corresponding $)$ is required too, of course. Also, you are using k twice in the second large formula: Once as a running variables, once as the dimension.

Comment: I completed the square for the Gaussian (please see my answer), but what do I do now? It is not obvious to me what - once I plugin this back into the integral - the result is (especially whether it is a Gaussian).

Comment: How does "The 's enforce =− on the < indices," happen?

Comment: Also: I think I was meaning of a Dirac delta and the epsilon from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3927949/opposite-of-delta-delta-distribution

Comment: @Make42 Integrating a test function $\int f(\xi)\delta(x-\xi-\mu)d\xi=f(x-\mu)$  so whenever we have such an integral we can replace $\xi$ with $x-\mu$.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer of user619894:

---

First we rewrite

\begin{align}
({\mathbf {\xi}_{>} }-{\boldsymbol {\mu }_{>}})^{\mathrm {T} }
{\boldsymbol {\Sigma }}^{-1}_{>>}
({\mathbf {\xi}_{>} }-{\boldsymbol {\mu }_{>}})+
2({\mathbf {x_{<}} }-{\boldsymbol {\mu }_{<}})^{\mathrm {T} }
{\boldsymbol {\Sigma }}^{-1}_{<>}
({\mathbf {\xi}_{>} }-{\boldsymbol {\mu }_{>}}) \\
\end{align}

with

\begin{align}
a &:= (\mathbf\xi_>-\boldsymbol\mu_>) \\
M &:= \boldsymbol\Sigma_{>>}^{-1} \\
b &:= -(({\mathbf {x_{<}} }-{\boldsymbol {\mu }_{<}})^{\mathrm {T} }
{\boldsymbol {\Sigma }}^{-1}_{<>})^{\mathrm {T} }
=
-(\boldsymbol\Sigma_{<>}^{-1})^T \cdot (\mathbf x_<-\boldsymbol\mu_<)
\end{align}

to

\begin{align}
 & a^T \cdot M \cdot a - 2 \cdot b^T \cdot a \\
=& (a-M^{-1}\cdot b)^T \cdot M \cdot (a-M^{-1}\cdot b) - b^T\cdot M^{-1} \cdot b \\
\end{align}

thanks to http://gregorygundersen.com/blog/2019/09/18/completing-the-square/ which becomes

\begin{align}
&( (\mathbf\xi_>-\boldsymbol\mu_>) + \boldsymbol\Sigma_{>>} \cdot (\boldsymbol\Sigma_{<>}^{-1})^T \cdot (\mathbf x_<-\boldsymbol\mu_<) )^T
\\
&\cdot \boldsymbol\Sigma_{>>}^{-1} \cdot
\\
&( (\mathbf\xi_>-\boldsymbol\mu_>) + \boldsymbol\Sigma_{>>} \cdot (\boldsymbol\Sigma_{<>}^{-1})^T \cdot (\mathbf x_<-\boldsymbol\mu_<) )
\\
&- (\mathbf x_<-\boldsymbol\mu_<)^T \cdot (\boldsymbol\Sigma_{<>}^{-1})^T \cdot \boldsymbol\Sigma_{>>} \cdot (\boldsymbol\Sigma_{<>}^{-1})^T \cdot (\mathbf x_<-\boldsymbol\mu_<)
\end{align}

Comment: The idea now is to notice that you can integrate over $d\xi$ and the result of the integral is not $x$ dependent, all the $x$ dependence is out of the integral, and you can combine it with the previous part to get a single Gaussian. I encourage you to push through the calculation yourself.

Comment: @user619894: Thank you for the encouragement! I know, that I need to but this back into the Gaussian inside the integral. But I really do not know how to integrate this afterwards analytically. Otherwise I would already have done it. Also, I do not see why you are writing why the result would not be depended on $x$. I believe you, I just don't fathom it.